# npm install fails to exec postinstall script bower install

Tags: npm, bower

I snooped around the net for more than 48 hours & failed to solve this.

When I run the command 'npm install', it fails to execute the postinstall script 'bower install'. So, I I did an explicit bower install by using:

```
$npm install -g bower

$bower install
```

After this, the 'app/bower_components' folder got populated alright. But, again when I try 'npm install', same issue. Unable to proceed further.

I performed the following & did not succeed in installing:

1. Git is installed & its path added in the PATH environment variable. And then run 'npm install'. Even restarted the command prompt in order for the PATH variable to reflect.
2. Run 'npm install restify', though I don't know why the installation has to be made a REST service.
   I used this, as it was one of the suggestions I came across.
3. In some post, it was mentioned that it could be due to firewall settings. Disabled the same & tried as well.
4. Changed all the files under my project 'angular-phonecat' to have read-write permissions. Did this by unchecking 'Read-only' option for the entire folder's contents.
5. Run Git Bash as admin & tried 'npm install'.

Please help me run this app. :(

Find below my logs:

```
600 info install angular-phonecat@0.0.0  
601 info postinstall angular-phonecat@0.0.0  
602 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true  
603 info angular-phonecat@0.0.0 Failed to exec postinstall script  
604 error angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`  
604 error spawn ENOENT  
605 error Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall script.  
605 error This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,  
605 error not with npm itself.  
605 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
605 error     bower install  
605 error You can get their info via:  
605 error     npm owner ls angular-phonecat  
605 error There is likely additional logging output above.  
606 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200  
607 error command "g:\\Workspace\\AngularProjects\\angular-phonecat\\node.exe" "g:\\Workspace\\AngularProjects\\angular-phonecat\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"  
608 error cwd g:\Workspace\AngularProjects\angular-phonecat  
609 error node -v v0.10.32  
610 error npm -v 1.4.28  
611 error syscall spawn  
612 error code ELIFECYCLE  
613 error errno ENOENT  
614 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide more information in order to get an answer to this question.  It looks like `angular-phonecat` is your own module that you created -- can you please publish its `package.json` as a gist https://gist.github.com and attach the link here?

Also, your `npm` is rather old (and was even at the time you asked this question).  I would recommend updating to the latest version of `npm`, which at this writing is 2.2.0.

To update npm on Windows, follow the instructions here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try [`npm-check`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) module to test if any component is outdated